# Error copying files from one project to another

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I've created a *.dll file in C++ to be used in a C# program. The native DLL resides in my managed DLL wrapper. From there, I physically copied my the native DLLs (NativeDll.dll for debug and release) into my C# console application's debug and release folders. When I run the C# program, it runs as expected creating objects and displaying values.

The problem comes when I changed a default value of a variable in my native library (C++). When I run the program again, the changes to the variable (the with of a box) still holds the last value. From what I've searched for, I've found that I could copy the dll from one project into my C# project by this means in the project's Build Events/Post-build event command line:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)ManagedDll\bin\$(Configuration)\NativeDll.dll"
      "$(SolutionDir)TestDLLConsole\bin\$(Configuration)"
```

When I run the program again, I get an error stating **"exited with code 9009."**
The only way around this is to manually re-copy my NativeDll.dll files and overwrite the existing one whenever I make changes.

The 4 projects I have in my solution are with next build depending on the previous:

- NativeLib (static library)
- NativeDll
- ManagedDll
- TestDLLConsole (where I test to see if the dll works).

How do I get the Dlls to be copied into/overwritten every TestDLLConsole is compiled?

Comment: You should never copy a dll from one project to another .  You loose the debugging features because the dll is no longer connected to the source data.  Instead when add one project to another from solution explorer : Add existing Item, then browse to location where dll is located.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I understand that. I had to do it that way first just to make sure the project worked. All the above projects were created within one solution. What I'm trying to achieve is that those files get over-written every time the program re-compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to overwrite the last dll that you copy with the last post build event. You can try:

```
copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)ManagedDll\bin\$(Configuration)\NativeDll.dll"
  "$(SolutionDir)TestDLLConsole\bin\$(Configuration)"
```

The /Y parameter suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.